# How to Build Qt to Cross Compile for Raspberry Pi3 on Windows

Tags: windows, cross-compiling, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, qt5.6

I have been trying to build qt for raspberry pi3 on windows for 6 months. I have tried lots of tutorials, read lots of forums but there is no successful result.

I can build qt on ubuntu 14.04 in virtualbox by following RaspberryPi2EGLFS, it has some error but I could solve them. I could deploy an application. I want to do same on windows.

There is a tutorial about building on windows in http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/ I can not build by following it.

A person who could build qt for raspberry pi3 wrote into qt forums by referencing tutorial above. https://forum.qt.io/topic/68381/cross-compile-qt-windows-to-raspberry-3 I tried this I get error again.

I tried lots of releases of QT such as 5.6.1, 5.7.0, 5.8.0, 5.6.2(Last released long term support version). Mingw versions greater than 4.9, MSVC2015 etc.

Every versions have different errors. 5.7.0 has a bug they said this bug is solved in 5.8.0 and there is another error in 5.8.0. This problems does not finish.

I just want to build qt easily for raspberry pi3 on windows.

**Please someone write a tutorial by giving all tools with working in harmony with a version that supports Raspberry Pi3**.

visualgdb gives links of compilers but they are old versions for Raspberry Pi3 and it has error and I can not build Qt.

> LAST OUTPUT :
>
> Performing shadow build... Preparing build tree... Running
>   configuration tests (phase 1)... Precompiled-headers support
>   enabled. C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c
>   -fvisibility=hidden fvisibility.c Symbol visibility control enabled. c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.gold.exe:
>   -plugin: unknown option c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.gold.exe:
>   use the --help option for usage information collect2.exe: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   --sysroot=C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -o libtest.so -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIC
>   bsymbolic_functions.c bsymbolic_functions.c:2:2: error: #error
>   "Symbolic function binding on this architecture may be broken,
>   disabling it (see QTBUG-36129)."
>   error "Symbolic function binding on this architecture may be broken, disabling it (see QTBUG-36129)." ^ Symbolic function binding disabled.
>   DEFAULT_INCDIRS="c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9
>   c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9/backward
>   c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include
>   c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include-fixed
>   c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
>   C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include "
>   DEFAULT_LIBDIRS="c
>   /sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/;c
>   /sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/;c
>   /sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/;c
>   /sysgcc/raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/;C
>   /SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/;C
>   /SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/lib/;C
>   /SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/;C
>   /SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib " Done running
>   configuration tests. Creating qmake...
>   C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -o qlibraryinfo.o
>   -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -ffunction-sections -O2 -DUNICODE -g -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/qmake -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/qmake/library -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/qmake/generators -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/qmake/generators/unix
>   -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/qmake/generators/win32
>   -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/qmake/generators/mac -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/qmake/generators/integrity
>   -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/include -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/include/QtCore -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.6.2 -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.6.2/QtCore
>   -I../src/corelib/global -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++ -IC:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/tools/shared -DQT_VERSION_STR="5.6.2" -DQT_VERSION_MAJOR=5 -DQT_VERSION_MINOR=6 -DQT_VERSION_PATCH=2 -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DPROEVALUATOR_FULL -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONLY_SHA1 -DQT_JSON_READONLY -DQT_NO_STANDARDPATHS C:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qlibraryinfo.cpp
>   arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error: command line option
>   '-fno-keep-inline-dllexport' is not supported by this configuration
>   make: *** [qlibraryinfo.o] Error 1

---

I change MinGW with 4.9.2 than I could generate qmake.exe Then, I change a line ( if true; then ###[ '!' -f "$outpath/bin/qmake" ]; to if [ '!' -f "$outpath/bin/qmake" ]; then ###[ '!' -f "$outpath/bin/qmake" ];) configure file in qtbase. I run configure again.

> $ ../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/configure -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rpi3-g++ -sysroot
>   C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5
>   -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -qt-xcb
>   -verbose

OUTPUT:

> Build options:   Configuration .......... accessibility
>   accessibility-atspi-bridge alsa audio-backend c++11 c++14
>   clock-gettime clock-monotonic compile_examples concurrent
>   cross_compile cups dbus egl eglfs eglfs_brcm enable_new_dtags evdev
>   eventfd freetype full-config getaddrinfo getifaddrs harfbuzz iconv icu
>   inotify ipv6ifname large-config largefile libudev linuxfb
>   medium-config minimal-config mremap neon opengl opengles2 openssl pcre
>   png posix_fallocate precompile_header qpa qpa reduce_exports release
>   rpath shared small-config system-jpeg system-zlib threadsafe-cloexec
>   xcb xcb-glx xcb-plugin xcb-qt xcb-xlib xinput2 xkbcommon-qt xlib
>   xrender   Build parts ............ libs   Mode ...................
>   release   Using sanitizer(s)...... none   Using C++ standard .....
>   c++14   Using gold linker....... no   Using new DTAGS ........ yes
>   Using PCH .............. yes   Using LTCG ............. no   Target
>   compiler supports:
>       Neon ................. yes
>
> Qt modules and options:   Qt D-Bus ............... yes (loading dbus-1
>   at runtime)   Qt Concurrent .......... yes   Qt GUI .................
>   yes   Qt Widgets ............. yes   Large File ............. yes
>   QML debugging .......... yes   Use system proxies ..... no
>
> Support enabled for:   Accessibility .......... yes   ALSA
>   ................... yes   CUPS ................... yes   Evdev
>   .................. yes   FontConfig ............. no   FreeType
>   ............... yes (bundled copy)   Glib ................... no
>   GStreamer .............. no   GTK theme .............. no   HarfBuzz
>   ............... yes (bundled copy)   Iconv .................. yes
>   ICU .................... yes   Image formats:
>       GIF .................. yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
>       JPEG ................. yes (plugin, using system library)
>       PNG .................. yes (in QtGui, using bundled copy)   libinput................ no   Logging backends:
>       journald ............... no
>       syslog   ............... no   mtdev .................. no   Networking:
>       getaddrinfo .......... yes
>       getifaddrs ........... yes
>       IPv6 ifname .......... yes
>       libproxy.............. no
>       OpenSSL .............. yes (loading libraries at run-time)   OpenGL / OpenVG:
>       EGL .................. yes
>       OpenGL ............... yes (OpenGL ES 2.0+)
>       OpenVG ............... no   PCRE ................... yes (bundled copy)   pkg-config ............. yes   PulseAudio ............. no
>   QPA backends:
>       DirectFB ............. no
>       EGLFS ................ yes
>         EGLFS i.MX6 ........ no
>         EGLFS i.MX6 Wayland. no
>         EGLFS EGLDevice .... no
>         EGLFS GBM .......... no
>         EGLFS Mali ......... no
>         EGLFS Raspberry Pi . yes
>         EGLFS X11 .......... no
>       LinuxFB .............. yes
>       Mir client............ no
>       XCB .................. yes (bundled copy)
>         EGL on X ........... no
>         GLX ................ yes
>         MIT-SHM ............ yes
>         Xcb-Xlib ........... yes
>         Xcursor ............ yes (loaded at runtime)
>         Xfixes ............. yes (loaded at runtime)
>         Xi ................. no
>         Xi2 ................ yes
>         Xinerama ........... yes (loaded at runtime)
>         Xrandr ............. yes (loaded at runtime)
>         Xrender ............ yes
>         XKB ................ yes
>         XShape ............. yes
>         XSync .............. yes
>         XVideo ............. yes   Session management ..... yes   SQL drivers:
>       DB2 .................. no
>       InterBase ............ no
>       MySQL ................ no
>       OCI .................. no
>       ODBC ................. yes (plugin)
>       PostgreSQL ........... no
>       SQLite 2 ............. no
>       SQLite ............... yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
>       TDS .................. yes (plugin)   tslib .................. no   udev ................... yes   xkbcommon-x11........... yes (bundled
>   copy, XKB config root: not found)   xkbcommon-evdev......... no   zlib
>   ................... yes (system library)
>
> WARNING: Could not find XKB config root, use -xkb-config-root to set a
>   path to XKB configuration data. This is required for keyboard input
>   support.
>
> NOTE: Qt is using double for qreal on this system. This is binary
>   incompatible against Qt 5.1. Configure with '-qreal float' to create a
>   build that is binary compatible with 5.1.
>
> Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'. Once everything is
>   built, you must run 'make install'. Qt will be installed into
>   /usr/local/qt5
>
> Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from the
>   previous build.
>
> **TheBUKs@DESKTOP-5D6JDFN MSYS /c/qt/qt-build $ make cd qtbase/ && ( test -e Makefile || C:/qt/qt-build/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe
>   C:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/qtbase.pro -o Makefile
>   ) && C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/make -f Makefile make[1]: Entering
>   directory `C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase' C:/qt/qt-build/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe
>   -o Makefile C:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/qtbase.pro make[1]: Leaving directory`C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase' make[1]: Entering
>   directory `C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase' cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile ||
>   C:/qt/qt-build/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe
>   C:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/src/src.pro -o
>   Makefile ) && C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/make -f Makefile make[2]:
>   Entering directory`C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase/src'
>   C:/qt/qt-build/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe -o Makefile
>   C:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/src/src.pro make[2]:
>   Leaving directory `C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase/src' make[2]: Entering
>   directory`C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase/src' cd corelib/ && ( test -e
>   Makefile.qtzlib || C:/qt/qt-build/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe
>   C:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/src/corelib/qtzlib.pro
>   -o Makefile.qtzlib ) && C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/make -f Makefile.qtzlib make[3]: Entering directory
>   `C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase/src/corelib'
>   C:/qt/qt-build/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe -o Makefile.qtzlib
>   C:/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.2/qtbase/src/corelib/qtzlib.pro
>   make[3]: Leaving directory`C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase/src/corelib'
>   make[3]: Entering directory `C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase/src/corelib'
>   make[3]: Nothing to be done for`first'. make[3]: Leaving directory
>   `C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase/src/corelib' The syntax of the command is
>   incorrect. make[2]: *** [sub-bootstrap-make_first] Error 1 make[2]:
>   Leaving directory`C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase/src' make[1]: ***
>   [sub-src-make_first] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   `C:/Qt/qt-build/qtbase' make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
>   *

Comment: Why building it on windows while you can easily boot a linux VM and crosscompile it from here with the official toolchain ?